# Knex(postres) - Is there a way to have a column unique only on some instances

Tags: database, postgresql, schema, knex.js

I have a table that has 3 columns (id, name, orgId(foreign key)
What I am trying to achieve is to have the column name unique if only the orgId matches

How do I define the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a unique constraint defined on both columns:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD UNIQUE (orgid, name);
```

That will exclude only rows where both `name` and `orgid` are identical to an already existing row.